# RelativeLayoutの両端にViewを配置する｡

Tags: android, android-layout

例えば以下のようなレイアウトにしたい場合

```html
------------------------------------------  
|xxxx  ←TextView                     yyyy|  ←RelativeLayout
|                                        |
|                                        |
|zzzz                                wwww|  ←RelativeLayout
------------------------------------------
```

`xxxx`と`zzzz`に`layout_alignParentLeft`と`layout_alignParentStart`を指定し､
`yyyy`と`wwww`に`layout_alignParentRight`と`layout_alignParentEnd`を指定しますが､もし`xxxx`と`zzzz`がとても長かった場合､右の`yyyy`と`wwww`にかかってしまいます｡
それを防ぐためには､どうすればいいのでしょうか｡
教えてください｡ よろしくおねがいします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xxxxに ToLeftOfで yyyy を指定すれば、yyyyの左側でxxxxが折り返すようになります。
zzzzとwwwwも同じ要領でいけるのではないでしょうか。